# Use wget to get resources of one page (but nothing else)

Tags: wget

I've downloaded and stored an `index.htm` page, and (depending on some criteria of this page) want to use wget to fetch all images, javascripts, css-files etc. a browser would download when displaying the page.

I currently use:

```
wget --server-response --timeout=120 --base="http://www.example.com/" --force-html --input-file="index.htm"
```

This works so far but it fetches as well all links defined like *a href="/somesubpage.htm"*. How can I avoid downloading the *a href*...?

Answer (score 1):

Since wget does not know how to execute javascript you have only 2 solutions :

- Make a request one the page with your browser and look at webserver logs. Then use wget on each one of the web page element.
- Use [phantomjs.](http://phantomjs.org).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is not executing javascript, I just want to download the javascript. The problem is that wget fetches all links as well which I don't want to (because there are a lot and I want to save bandwidth).